# css, float:left, keep text in own column

Tags: css

I have two float:left elements next to each other. When the parent element is too narrow to fit both texts on one line, then I want the text to go down to the next row, but each in their own "column". The parent width is flexible so I do not know what it will be.

http://jsfiddle.net/jsHCJ/1/ illustrates the problem and what I would like the solution to look like.

```
<div id = "page2">
    <div class = "f1">
        float 1
    </div>
    <div class = "f2">
        float 2 and long
    </div>
</div>

#page2 {width:110px; }  

.f1{ 
  background:pink; 
 float:left;
}

.f2{
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: i think you should increase #page2 width

Comment: No, I cannot. That's the point.

Comment: than use white-space:nowrap

Comment: if you dont want to increase the page width  then remove the #page2

Comment: use font-size: 12px; in #page2

Comment: yes i fount  use   display: inline;  in #page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Use `display:table-cell;` for both the divs.

What this will do is when the page shrinks or expands, the div will be at the same place and shall take the text to expand or shrink accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! - I think it's funny that everyone was so much against the use of tables for layout that they had to create another way to essentially make tables :)

Answer (score 0):

if i was you, i will use

```
display: table-cell
```

I've updated your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jsHCJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css for #page 2 to like this

```
#page2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: without display: inline-block; ? nothing is change

Answer (score 0):

try to add   css  in #page2

```
display: inline;
```

this will solve your problum